# Etiquette of deleting comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

I'd like to delete the comments I made [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12763/472) about calendar reform because (1) I was totally misremembering and (2) just before realizing that I shared a link to that fascinating post on my blog.  So not only was I an idiot but it'll be embarrassing in front of my friends (and others).  I could delete my own comments, but that'll leave a partial thread that'll be a little confusing.  What is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't say what's right. (Because I don't know, not because it's a secret.) But:

- I frequently see (on other SE sites) comments that are replies to nonexistent comments, indicating deletion. So it's not uncommon.
- There's always the possibility of deleting your own comments and @ddressing your interlocutor indicating that you've done so, which will allow him to delete his if he so desires. If it's confusing to third parties, IMO tough luck.

Comment: You can also delete your comments and flag the others as obsolete.